# Are there any very simple RSA implementation in C++

Tags: rsa

Are there any very simple cross-platform C++ libs which can do assymetric encription? 
Not necessary efficient, just working. I imagine it could be just 3-4 functions in an .h file which do arbitrary precission math and that's it.

I belive using OpenSSL here is an overkill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://cryptopp.com/ looks to be what I need.
One might tear it down to individual files, and it has RSA samples.

Comment: +1 for crypto++. Often "simple" RSA implementations are lacking essential things, such as a secure padding. crypto++, as far as I can judge is carefully implemented and some versions of it have gone through NIST certification.

Comment: @Accipitridae: b-b-but he answered his *own* question, and he's been a SO user for 7 months!

Comment: @GregS: I don't get you irony here :-)

Comment: @GregS: Yup. I noticed. Maybe you can regard this as a vote for Wei Dai's work.